# Recycler view, Android

Tags: java, android

У меня есть фрагмент, он хранит список CardView и доп. информацию(назову ее "информация A"). CardView размещаются в RecyclerView. Кликая по CardView, открывается диалог в котором есть кнопки, по нажатию на которые, информация A должна измениться. Структура классов следующая: Есть класс фрагмента, класс адаптера под RecyclerView, класс Holder для CardView, которыми оперирует Адаптер. В общем стандартная схема. Все классы реализованы как отдельный в отдельном файле. Вопрос следующий, как правильно запрограммировать схему, по которой информацию A будет изменяться по клику в Диалоге. Свой код не буду выставлять, так как меня интересует именно ваш подход, как вообще правильно такие вещи программировать.

Comment: из вопроса совершенно не ясно, в чем именно проблема и что у вас не получается сделать для ее решения, так же нет никакой информации о способе хранения данных, а это напрямую влияет на алгоритм. сам алгоритм очевиден и прост - при вызове диалога получаете данные айтема, с которого вызывали, изменяете их и обновляете список

Comment: как я должен вызвать метод обновляющий информацию A по нажатию кнопки в диалоге

Answer (score 0):

Ты открываешь диалоговое окно, получаешь в нем объект и изменяешь его. Добавляешь в лист под тем же id, и обновляешь свой адаптер. В идеале ещё сделать свой DiffUtils класс. Может что-то упустил, но должно быть так.